# How to get access to my own files using PHP SDK in Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

This is what I've tried:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(Mage::getBaseDir('etc') . '/test-7b390c56695f.json');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setApplicationName('artsdecors-test');
$this->service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo($file->getMimeType() . "\n");
}
```

This retrieved only one file ("application/pdf" with title "Getting started"), not my own files.  What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine if the `test-7b390c56695f.json` is the `client-secret.json` produced in the Google Developer Console.

You have to be properly authenticated to be able to retrieve your own files. The [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) is a good place to begin learning how the Drive API works. Once done, you can now check out on the proper [authentication scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) you'll be needing for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The client is authenticating with credentials in the .json file, most likely. Are those your accurate credentials, or a set of test credentials provided with the SDK?

Disclaimer: I have never worked with the drive sdk, only suggesting what might be an issue here.